# Python blank txt file creation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create bulk text files based on list. A text file has number of lines/titles and aim is to create text files. Following is how my titles.txt looks like along with non-working code and expected output.

```
titles = open("C:\\Dropbox\\Python\\titles.txt",'r')  
for lines in titles.readlines():  
       d_path = 'C:\\titles'     
   output = open((d_path.lines.strip())+'.txt','a')  
   output.close()  
titles.close()
```

`titles.txt

   Title-A

   Title-B

   Title-C`

`new blank files to be created under directory c:\\titles\\

   Title-A.txt

   Title-B.txt

   Title-C.txt`

Comment: Just a suggestion: you probably want to use [os.path.join()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of string concatenation and strip() etc.

Comment: rather than appending, maybe you should open with "w" option?

Comment: (1) what is your problem ? (2) Are you sure about the syntax `d_path.lines.strip()`? Are you trying to concatenate some strings?

Comment: @seckin-savasci 10x, tried with "w" & "w+" but no luck.

Comment: I don't think the problem you are having is quite clear, could you perhaps update your post with a bit more explanation about the problem you are having?

Comment: @pierre-gm i just want to use d_path so all files created in particular directory.

Comment: @user1582596 Once again, *check your syntax*: the `d_path.lines.strip()` should look weird to you. Besides, I was asking you about the problem/error you're having, not about your goal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little difficult to tell what you're attempting here, but hopefully this will be helpful:

```
import os.path
with open('titles.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        newfile = os.path.join('C:\\titles',line.strip()) + '.txt'
        ff = open( newfile, 'a')
        ff.close()
```

If you want to replace existing files with blank files, you can open your files with mode `'w'` instead of `'a'`.

Comment: wouldn't you want `w` as mode? (thought the proplem is still a bit unclear as posted by OP)

Comment: @Levon -- that depends on whether the user wants to replace *existing files* with blank ones.  using `'w'` seems dangerous to me, so I avoided that, but I updated with a comment.

Comment: Yes .. good point .. hopefully OP will clarify (your edit is good)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work.

```
import os
titles='C:/Dropbox/Python/titles.txt'
d_path='c:/titles'
with open(titles,'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        with open(os.path.join(d_path,l.strip()),'w') as _:
            pass
```